# void main method in an implementation section of the class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I saw a class (inherits from `NSOperation` class) with .h and .m files as usual, but in the implementation section there is `-(void) main` method and `NSAutoReleasePool` object, it looks like the main method of the application itself, why there should be a method with this name in a .m file ?

Comment: Hey, I answered your question as asked and you changed the question and gave the points to someone else :-D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is just a method on `NSOperation`. The difference is:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
```

Is a C **function** which is where the program starts

```
- (void)main;
```

Is an objective-C **instance method** on a **class**.

The reason it has it's own auto releasepool is that it is generally called on a separate thread therefore this new thread needs to deal with auto released objects.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's a NSThread or NSOperation subclass? They have their own main() methods.

Comment: i have updated my question above, so is it a standard way for dealing with these classes ? and can you explain why to have a main method in them ?

Answer (score 1):

to quote apple docs...

> NSThread.h main
>
> The main entry point routine for the thread.
>   - (void)main Discussion
>
> The default implementation of this method takes the target and
>   selector used to initialize the receiver and invokes the selector on
>   the specified target. If you subclass NSThread, you can override this
>   method and use it to implement the main body of your thread instead.
>   If you do so, you do not need to invoke super.
>
> You should never invoke this method directly. You should always start
>   your thread by invoking the start method. Availability

so that is the use of main in every thread and every thread has an autorelease pool for itself .. hope that helps.